# Cannot create MySQL table via design view in Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have successfully created a connection to MySQL 8.0.29 through Visual Studio 2019 and I am able to list tables and views in various MySQL databases. I am trying to create tables in the Server Explorer side pane under the Data Connections section but I get the error:

---

[image: Visual Studio 2019 Server Explorer error]

I have both MySQL .NET connector v8.0.29 and MySQL for Visual Studio v1.2.10 installed. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by downgrading the MySQL .NET Connector from v8.0.29 to v8.0.28.